# Why Ctrl+Tab doesn't work anymore in my QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

There is `QTabWidget` in my application. `Ctrl+Tab` does not toggle tabs. But I noticed `Ctrl+Tab` works for new `QTabWidget`. May be I accidentally removed this action. I don't know.
What can be a reason and how can I restore tabs toggling by `Ctrl+Tab`?

Comment: Some workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160232/qt-designer-shortcut-to-another-tab)

Comment: you might have disabled, keyboad focus for QTabWidget using "setFocusPolicy( Qt::NoFocus)?

Comment: @Ashif does not work regardless the policy